# Как отключить owlCarousel на мобиле

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, owl-carousel

Проблема простая, но все что я находил в интернете не работает. Ничего не изменяется. Карусель тоже простая, а отключить ее на мобильном не могу.

```js
$(".content-in").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    nav:false,
    mouseDrag:false,
    smartSpeed:800,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Заверни запуск карусели в функцию и инициализируй её только когда разрешение экрана >768px (Можешь ещё событие resize повесить если тебе очень надо для отслеживания, но не рекомендую)

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с предыдущим ответом, но функцию вводить не обязательно. Можете просто завернуть инициализацию в условие. Как вам больше нравится.

```
if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth > 767 ){
  $(".content-in").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    nav:false,
    mouseDrag:false,
    smartSpeed:800,
  });
}
```